# How to show modal from another html after a successful form submission?

Tags: django, modal-dialog

## Here is the code I'm currently using. I've been trying to figure out how to solve this but I think I can't since it been hours. Any suggestions and answer will be appreciated.

## urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import pos, save_pos, receipt

app_name = 'pos'

urlpatterns = [
    path('point-of-sale/', pos, name='point-of-sale'),
    path('save-pos/', save_pos, name='save-pos'),
    path('receipt/<int:transaction_id>/', receipt, name='receipt-modal'),
]
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from shop.models import Items
from .models import Transaction, TransactionItems
from .forms import TransactionForm
from datetime import datetime
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
import json


def pos(request):
    products = Items.objects.filter(is_sold=False)
    product_json = [{'id':product.pk, 'name':product.name, 'price':float(product.price)} for product in products]
    context = {
        'products' : products,
        'product_json' : json.dumps(product_json)
    }
    return render(request, 'pos.html', context)

def save_pos(request):
    pref = datetime.now().year + datetime.now().year
    i = 1
    while True:
        code = '{:0>5}'.format(i)
        i += int(1)
        check = Transaction.objects.filter(code = str(pref) + str(code)).all()
        if len(check) <= 0:
            break
    code = str(pref) + str(code)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TransactionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            product_ids = form.cleaned_data.get('product_ids', [])
            product_quantities = form.cleaned_data.get('product_quantities', [])

            subtotals = []
            for product_id, quantity in zip(product_ids, product_quantities):
                product = Items.objects.get(id=product_id)
                product_price = product.price
                subtotal = quantity * product_price
                subtotals.append(subtotal)

            transaction = Transaction.objects.create(code=code)
            transaction.tendered_amount = request.POST.get('tendered_amount', 0)
            transaction.amount_change = request.POST.get('amount_change', 0)
            transaction.total_price += sum(subtotals)
            transaction.save()

            latest_transaction_id = Transaction.objects.last().pk

            for product_id, quantity, subtotal in zip(product_ids, product_quantities, subtotals):
                latest_transaction = Transaction.objects.filter(id=latest_transaction_id).first()
                product = Items.objects.filter(id=product_id).first()
                transaction_item = TransactionItems(
                    transaction_id=latest_transaction,
                    item_id=product,
                    price=product.price,
                    qty=quantity,
                    sub_total=subtotal
                )
                transaction_item.save()
            

            return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'transaction_id': latest_transaction_id}, safe=False)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'errors': form.errors}, safe=False)

    else:
        form = TransactionForm()
        return render(request, 'pos.html', {'form': form})


def receipt(request, transaction_id):
    transactions = get_object_or_404(Transaction, pk=transaction_id)
    transaction_items = TransactionItems.objects.filter(transaction_id=transactions)
    context = {
        'transactions' : transactions,
        'transaction_items' : transaction_items
    }
    return render(request, 'receipt_modal.html', context)
```

## You can ignore other errrors other than the modal I'm asking for but of course any help will be much appreciated

## pos.html

```
{% extends "base_templates\main.html" %}
{% load humanize %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}Point of Sale {% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    
    <div class="container">
        <form method="post" action="" id="transaction_form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="text-center mb-4">
                <h2>Point of Sales</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row g-5">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productId" placeholder="Product ID">
                        <input type="hidden" name="product_ids" id="product_ids" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="productQty" value=1 >
                        <input type="hidden" name="product_quantities" id="product_quantities" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-2">
                <div class="col-md-9" style="height:450px; overflow: auto;">
                    <table class="table table-striped" id="productTable">
                        <thead class="table table-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                <th>Subtotal</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="total-label">Total: </span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" aria-label="0.00" aria-describedby="total-label" id="total" readonly>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="receive-label">Amount Receive:</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" aria-label="0.00" aria-describedby="receive-label" id="amount_receive">
                        <input type="hidden" name="tendered_amount" id="tendered_amount" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="change-label">Change:</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" aria-label="0.00" aria-describedby="change-label" id="change" readonly>
                        <input type="hidden" name="amount_change" id="amount_change" value="">
                    </div>               
                    <div class="col-md-4 offset-8">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#receipt-modal" id="check_out">Checkout</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="modal_handler"></div>
    </div>
    

 {% endblock content %} 
 
 {% block ScriptBlock %}
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var product_json = '{{ product_json }}';
            if (product_json == "" || product_json == "{}") {
                product_json = {};
            } else {
                product_json = product_json.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
                product_json = $.parseJSON(product_json);
            }
        
            var typingTimer;
            var doneTypingInterval = 100;
        
            $('#productId').on('input', function () {
                clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        
                typingTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                    var productId = $('#productId').val();
                    var productQty = parseInt($('#productQty').val());
        
                    if (!productId || productQty < 1) {
                        alert('Please enter both a valid Product ID and a Quantity greater than 0.');
                        return;
                    }

                    var productDetails = fetchProductDetails(productId);
                    var existingRow = $('#productTable tbody tr').filter(function() {
                        return $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text() === productDetails.name;
                    });
        
                    if (existingRow.length > 0) {
                        var existingQty = parseInt(existingRow.find('td:nth-child(4)').text());
                        var newQty = existingQty + productQty;
                        existingRow.find('td:nth-child(4)').text(newQty);
                        var newSubtotal = productDetails.price * newQty;
                        existingRow.find('td:nth-child(5)').text(formatNumber(newSubtotal));
                    } else {
                        var subtotal = productDetails.price * productQty;
        
                        var newRow = $('<tr id="' + productId + '">');
                        newRow.append($('<td><button class="btn btn-danger remove-item" data-item="' + productId + '">Remove</button></td>'));
                        newRow.append($('<td>' + productDetails.name + '</td>'));
                        newRow.append($('<td>' + formatNumber(productDetails.price) + '</td>'));
                        newRow.append($('<td>' + productQty + '</td>'));
                        newRow.append($('<td>' + formatNumber(subtotal) + '</td>'));
        
                        $('#productTable tbody').append(newRow);
                        $('.remove-item[data-item="' + productId + '"]').click(function () {
                            var rowToRemove = $('#' + productId);
                            $(this).off('click');
                            rowToRemove.remove();
                            updateTotal();
                            $(this).click(function () {
                                rowToRemove.remove();
                                updateTotal();
                            });
                        });
                    }
                    $('#productId').val('');
                    $('#productId').focus();
                    $('#productQty').val(1);
                    updateTotal();
                }, doneTypingInterval);
            });

            $('#productId').on('input', function () {
                var productId = $('#productId').val();
                var productQty = parseInt($('#productQty').val());
                
                var id_exist = $('#product_ids').val();
                var qty_exist = $('#product_quantities').val();
            
                var idArray = id_exist ? id_exist.split(',') : [];
                var qtyArray = qty_exist ? qty_exist.split(',') : [];
            
                var index = idArray.indexOf(productId);
            
                if (index !== -1) {
                    qtyArray[index] = parseInt(qtyArray[index]) + productQty;
                } else {
                    idArray.push(productId);
                    qtyArray.push(productQty);
                }
                $('#product_ids').val(idArray.join(','));
                $('#product_quantities').val(qtyArray.join(','));
            
                console.log('Saved Data: ' + $('#product_ids').val() + ' : ' + $('#product_quantities').val());
            });
            
            $('#amount_receive').on('input', function () {
                var total = unformatNumber($('#total').val());
                var cash = parseFloat($('#amount_receive').val());
                var change = cash - total;
            
                if (change < 0) {
                    $('#change').val('0.00');
                } else {
                    $('#change').val(formatNumber(change));
                    $('#tendered_amount').val(cash);
                    $('#amount_change').val(change)
                }
            });
            
            $('#check_out').click(function () {
                var total = unformatNumber($('#total').val());
                var cash = parseFloat($('#amount_receive').val());

                if ($('#productTable tbody tr').length < 1) {
                    alert('Add at least 1 item before checking out.')
                    return false;
                }
                if (cash < total || !cash) {
                    alert('Please enter the appropriate amount.');
                    return false;
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: '{% url "pos:save-pos" %}',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: $('#transaction_form').serialize(),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success) {
                            displayReceiptModal(data.transaction_id);
                        } else {
                            if (data.errors) {
                                alert('Form submission failed. Please check the form for errors.');
                            } else {
                                alert('An error occurred. Please try again.');
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
                
            });

            function displayReceiptModal(transactionId) {
                $.ajax({
                  url: '/receipt/' + transactionId + '/',
                  method: 'GET',
                  success: function (data) {
                    $('#modal_handler').html(data);
                    $('#receipt-modal').modal('show');
                  },
                  error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                  }
                });
              }
            

            function fetchProductDetails(productId) {
                var prod_arr = {};
                if (Object.keys(product_json).length > 0) {
                    Object.keys(product_json).map(k => {
                        prod_arr[product_json[k].id] = product_json[k];
                    });
                }
                var productDetails = prod_arr[productId];
                if (productDetails) {
                    var product_name = productDetails.name;
                    var product_price = productDetails.price;
                }
                return {
                    name: product_name,
                    price: product_price
                };
            }
            
            function formatNumber(number) {
                if (typeof number === 'number' && !isNaN(number)) {
                    let formattedNumber = number.toFixed(2);
                    let parts = formattedNumber.split('.');
                    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
                    return parts.join('.');
                } else {
                    return '0.00';
                }
            }

            function unformatNumber(formattedNumber) {
                let unformattedNumber = formattedNumber.replace(/,/g, '');
                return parseFloat(unformattedNumber);
            }

            function updateTotal() {
                var total_payable = 0;
                var modalData = '';
                var total_qty = 0;
            
                $('#productTable tbody tr').each(function() {
                    var subtotal = $(this).find('td:nth-child(5)').text();
                    var total = unformatNumber(subtotal);
                    total_payable += parseFloat(total);
                });
                $('#total').val(formatNumber(total_payable));
            }

            function print() {
                var print_window = window.open('', '_blank', "width=800,height=800,left=300, top = 200")
                var content = document.getElementById('modal-content').innerHTML;

                print_window.document.open();
                print_window.document.write('<html><head><title>Print</title></head><body>');
                print_window.document.write(content);
                print_window.document.write('</body></html>');
                print_window.document.close();
        
                print_window.print();
            }
        });
    </script>
{% endblock ScriptBlock %}
```

## receipt_modal.html

```
{% load humanize %}

<div class="modal fade" id="receipt-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="receipt-modal-label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" style="text-align: center;">Transaction</h5>
            </div>  
            <div class="modal-body" id="modal-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 offset-3 text-center">
                        <h6>DaveTeo Classic Bikeshop</h6>
                        <h7>Official Receipt</h7>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <span id="date">Date: {{ transactions.date_saved}}</span>
                    <span id="transaction_code">Transaction Code: {{ transactions.code }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2"><span class="fw-bold">QTY</span></div>
                    <div class="col-6"><span class="fw-bold">Item/Price</span></div>
                    <div class="col-4"><span class="fw-bold">Amount</span></div>
                </div>
                {% for item in transaction_items %}
                <div class="row mb-0"><div class="col-6 offset-2">{{ item.item_id.name }}</div></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">{{ item.qty | floatformat:0 }}</div>
                    <div class="col-6">{{ item.price | intcomma }}</div>
                    <div class="col-4">{{ item.sub_total | intcomma }}</div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <hr>  
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-9 fw-bold">Total Amount:</div>
                        <div class="col-3" id="total_amount">{{ transactions.total_price | intcomma }}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-9 fw-bold">Tendered Amount: </div>
                    <div class="col-3" id="tendered_amount">{{ transactions.tendered_amount | intcomma }}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-9 fw-bold">Change Amount: </div>
                    <div class="col-3" id="change_amount">{{ transactions.amount_change | intcomma }}</div>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onClick="closeModal()" id="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" id="print" onClick="print()" class="btn btn-primary">Print</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```